# Progress 9.1e + Datadirect 4.10 Freezes Whole System

Tags: odbc, progress-4gl, openedge

We've had a problem for almost a year now which we have not been able to put the finger on it.

We have software made by an external Company that uses Progress v9.1E and in that same Server we also have a MySQL DB that are used by some in-house made software coded with VB.

These are the current server specs where we have Progress installed

- Progress v9.1E that uses the ODBC driver Datadirect 4.10
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bits
- 16GB RAM

This issue, makes the Server to use all CPU and DISK I/O, such that at some point everyone who is using an application from this Server is unable to work. For now, each time this happens we restart the Server.

It happens as often as once a week.

Any of you might have an idea or pointer how can this happen, what can make the CPU and DISK to be that high?

How would you isolate this problem?

Hope I'm clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue is very unclear. Is some unnamed ODBC client application connecting to Progress, and its interaction leading to the resource consumption spike you describe? (How are you sure it's Progress and/or ODBC that's spiking CPU & disk usage?) You might try a different ODBC Driver (such as [from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-progress/)), or update the client application, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad topic.  I'm not sure that it really meets the stackoverflow Q&A model.  You are going to need a lot of debugging and  clarifications to get anywhere with this.  IMHO you'd be a lot better served posting to a forum that is more suited to back and forth conversations:

[The "official" Progress community forums](https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_rdbms/)

[ProgressTalk - an independent forum for discussing Progress](http://www.progresstalk.com/)